# Calling Methods of Pattern Library into Activity

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Pattern Lock Library from:
https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/source/browse/

After import to library I am not able to call a single function of library, Whenever I run my app,getting force close with inflate exception.Please anyone solve my problem.
          Sorry for my bad english

```
 package com.example.otpdemo;


  import group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.widget.Button;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  char[] savedPattern;
  private static final int REQ_CREATE_PATTERN = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN, null,
  MainActivity.this,LockPatternActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CREATE_PATTERN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CREATE_PATTERN: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            char[] pattern = data.getCharArrayExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN);

        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

LOgcat Error:

11-13 12:40:53.690: E/AndroidRuntime(1389): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.otpdemo/group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.widget.LockPatternView_v14

11-13 12:40:53.690: E/AndroidRuntime(1389):  at      group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity.initContentView(LockPatternActivity.java:7)

Comment: Please add the logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

are you Eclipse user? how are you importing this library? you should download library project, unpack and import (folder code inside zip), then right click on -> Properties -> Android section and there check "Is library". Then in your app do the same, left "is library" unchecked and press "Add" button and add lib

Comment: your added log says inflate exception, so check out XML which is inflated in LockPatternActivity (if you have there custom Views from lib you must use full packacke, e.g. <com.lib.views.LockView .../>, it's common problem for users to use LockView). probably you've properly imported lib and problem isn't on this side

Comment: Actually there are also full package named xml, So do you have any other option for pattern lock ?

Comment: dunno why, my own import works well.. maybe wrong version of support package if needed (just a guess). also try clean imported lib and your project. also avoid to call new Activity inside OnCreate previous Activity, but I don't think that it causes this err